# MacBook Pro trackpad click

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, multi-touch

I am new to the MacBook Pro laptop. Why does the trackpad have to be pressed down to register a click, rather than just touching on the pad? Is there a way to change this? Please advise because it is very irritating to have to press hard on the trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "Tap-To-Click" in the **System Preferences**.

Go to `System Preferences` from the  menu, and click on `Trackpad`. (near the middle of the screen)

There should be a screen that looks like this:

[image]